# ExpandoObject C# IL

Tags: c#, dynamic, il, expandoobject

Currently I have the following il code:

```
var method = new DynamicMethod( "", typeof( object ), new Type[ 0 ] );
var emiter = method.GetILGenerator();
var expando = emiter.DeclareLocal( typeof( ExpandoObject ) );
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Newobj, typeof( ExpandoObject ).GetConstructors()[ 0 ] );
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Stloc, expando );

var value = emiter.DeclareLocal( typeof( int ) );
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1 );
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Stloc, value );

emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Ldloc, expando );
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Ldnull );
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Ldc_I4, -1 );
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Ldloc, value );
if ( value.LocalType.IsValueType )
    emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Box, value.LocalType );
else
{
    emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Castclass, typeof( object ) );
}
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Ldstr, "Test" );
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0 );
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1 );
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Call, typeof( ExpandoObject ).GetMethod( "TrySetValue", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic ) );

emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Ldloc, expando );
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Ret );
var @delegate = (Func<dynamic>)method.CreateDelegate( typeof( Func<dynamic> ) );

var result = @delegate().Test;
```

It working fine when I initially wrote it in sigil but now I converted it to DynamicMethod I am getting this error. I copied the Sigil code exactly and have triple checked it. Does anybody have an ideas thanks in advance.

> Attempt by method 'DynamicClass.()' to access method 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject.TrySetValue(System.Object, Int32, System.Object, System.String, Boolean, Boolean)' failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by adding restrictedSkipVisibility to the DynamicMethod Constructor.

```
var method = new DynamicMethod( "", typeof( object ), new Type[ 0 ], true  );
var emiter = method.GetILGenerator();
var expando = emiter.DeclareLocal( typeof( ExpandoObject ) );
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Newobj, typeof( ExpandoObject ).GetConstructors()[ 0 ] );
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Stloc, expando );

var value = emiter.DeclareLocal( typeof( int ) );
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1 );
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Stloc, value );

emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Ldloc, expando );
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Ldnull );
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Ldc_I4, -1 );
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Ldloc, value );
if ( value.LocalType.IsValueType )
    emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Box, value.LocalType );
else
{
    emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Castclass, typeof( object ) );
}
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Ldstr, "Test" );
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0 );
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1 );
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Call, typeof( ExpandoObject ).GetMethod( "TrySetValue", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic ) );

emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Ldloc, expando );
emiter.Emit( OpCodes.Ret );
var @delegate = (Func<dynamic>)method.CreateDelegate( typeof( Func<dynamic> ) );

var result = @delegate().Test;
```